# Can Red Hat and Ubuntu Share swap

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, swap

I already have Red Hat installed. When I install Ubuntu, the swap area for the already-installed Red Hat was identified by the Ubuntu installer, and the default option is to "Use as: swap area".

The issue I have is that when I click "Install Now", the installer asks me to confirm that I'm formatting the Red Hat swap area as "swap".

Questions:

1. Does this mean somehow the Red Hat swap and Ubuntu swap uses different file systems or formats?
2. What filesystem is swap anyways?
3. If I use the default option, "Use as: swap area" for the swap already configured for Red Hat, and Ubuntu proceeds with the format, will Red Hat still be able to that area as swap when in the future (when I boot into it in the future)?

Answer (score 4):

You can share the swap partition among multiple linux (and even windows) operating systems. Swap partition is a space used by the OS to move idle/unused pages from the RAM when the RAM is full. When you install Ubuntu, you can choose "Use as: swap area" to tell ubuntu to use that partition at its swap. Also it is better to make sure that Redhat is not hibernated as Ubuntu will need to format the swap partition.

You might have some disadvantages. One being the inability to hibernate one OS while booting other.

Answer (score 3):

1. No.
2. Swap is no actual file system. It is just a reserved part of the disk that is raw addressable memory with no special structure. Quoted from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/172724/what-file-system-is-swap-on-linux).
3. Yes, however you have to be careful with hibernate and/or suspend. In this case the OS stores RAM contents in the swap area. If another OS then uses that space itself, that stored state will be lost and it will become impossible to restart the suspended OS into its saved state. When you boot that OS, it will be as if the system crashed -- open files may be damaged, file systems may need repair, etc. If you want to hibernate/suspend, do not share swap partitions (or file systems)

Comment: If the Ubuntu installer "reformats" the swap partition, it may be necessary to change the UUID value (if one is used) in Red Hat's `/etc/fstab` file. The issue with hibernate/suspend is that the OS stores RAM contents in the swap area. If another OS then uses that space itself, that stored state will be lost and it will become impossible to restart the suspended OS into its saved state. When you boot that OS, it will be as if the system crashed -- open files may be damaged, filesystems may need repair, etc. If you want to hibernate/suspend, do not share swap partitions (or filesystems).

Comment: @RodSmith. I included your comment in my answer. I hope this is ok.

Comment: I am grateful to everyone who took the time to respond to my question. I'm still looking into the possibility of needing to modify `/etc/fstab` and will report back soon.

Comment: @RodSmith Would you explain how I could determine whether it is necessary to change the UUID value in Red Hat's /etc/fstab file?

Comment: Type `sudo blkid /dev/{whatever}`, where `/dev/{whatever}` is the path to your swap partition. This will show the UUID value, among other things. Then load `/etc/fstab` into a text editor and look for the swap line. If the UUID doesn't match what you found via `blkid`, then you must change it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes they can share swap. In fact, every Linux OS can.

By default they do not share swap. You have to choose that manually from the advanced install options (chose "Something else..." when you have to decide how/where you want to install Ubuntu). And swap is not that important if you don't use the hibernation or suspend functionality. When you hibernate, data from RAM is stored in swap.

Comment: Thanks! But why does the Ubuntu installer reformats the swap partition?

Comment: Your answer is a bit short. Please [edit] it to provide more detail and explanation. You can e.g. include the hibernation problem into your answer: If you hibernate one system, it stores the RAM in the swap partition. So if one boots the second OS now which uses the partition as swap, the hibernation data is gone (or the second OS maybe could recognize it and disable swapping, which is also not good). The OP also asked about the file system type... Thank you!